# HTTP Error 404.3 Not Found in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting the error [HTTP Error 404.3 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc8uj.jpg)

whenever run the code on the hosting server but not in localhost.

I have created web pages in classic asp (.asp ext).

Please help me, why this error is coming.

[image: HTTP error 404.3]

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET if you're using Classic ASP?

Comment: Are you sure you have deployed your files properly? Does your hosting provider support classic ASP?